# magento override billing and shipping last name

Tags: module, shipping, billing

I dont want to show last name from billing and shipping name everywhere like invoice , sales order , how can i do same with out changing from database please help me with same .

i am  new to magento and do want want to change core files for it , any over to override last name to null ?

Answer (score 0):

**Step -1**
Go to **Store->Setting->Configuration->Customerts->Customer Configuration->Name and Address Option->Address Templates**

[image]

**Step -2**
Remove **{{/depend}}{{var lastname}}** from All Address Templates and **Save config**

**I hope this is helpful to you!!**